# A metric space is separable if it contains a countable dense subset. Show that $R^k$ is separable.

Tags: real-analysis

> A metric space is separable if it contains a countable dense subset. Show that $R^k$ is separable.

I am thinking about proof by induction. But I am not even sure how to argue, say $R^1$ is separable due to lack of understanding of definitions.

Neighborhood is defined to be $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ for $x,y \in R^k$.

Dense means a subset E in a set X is dense if every point of X is a limit point of E.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Think rationally! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $\Bbb Q^k$?  Use that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$.